# Batch exe to shortcut

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, shortcut

Currently, I am attempting to create a shortcut for a program, I was able to do so shown in the code below.

```
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Unturned Dedicated Server\Unturned - Server.lnk" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs
del CreateShortcut.vbs
```

The issue is I need the target path to be, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe" -batchmode -nographics +secureserver/ahhh`

How would I go about doing so?

Comment: You should add another line where to put the arguments to be passed to your .exe target

Comment: Try `echo oLink.Arguments = -batchmode -nographics +secureserver/ahhh >> CreateShortcut.vbs`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this as a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), which creates a vbscript, runs it, then deletes it, I'd suggest that you do it like this:

```batch-file
@(  Echo Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    Echo strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
    Echo str32bitPF = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%"^)
    Echo Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    Echo If Not (oFSO.FolderExists(strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server"^)^) Then
    Echo   oFSO.CreateFolder(strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server"^)
    Echo End If
    Echo Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server\Unturned - Server.lnk"^)
    Echo oShellLink.Arguments = "-batchmode -nographics +secureserver/ahhh"
    Echo oShellLink.TargetPath = str32bitPF + "\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe"
    Echo oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
    Echo oShellLink.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+U"
    Echo oShellLink.Description = "Launch Unturned"
    Echo oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server"
    Echo oShellLink.Save) > "CreateShortcut.vbs"
@%__AppDir__%cscript.exe /NoLogo "CreateShortcut.vbs"
@Del "CreateShortcut.vbs"
```

However, you can also do it directly from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) without writing to a file too.

```batch-file
<!-- :
@%__AppDir__%cscript.exe /NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"
@GoTo :EOF
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
str32bitPF = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not (oFSO.FolderExists(strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server")) Then
oFSO.CreateFolder(strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server")
End If
Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server\Unturned - Server.lnk")
oShellLink.Arguments = "-batchmode -nographics +secureserver/ahhh"
oShellLink.TargetPath = str32bitPF + "\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe"
oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
oShellLink.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+U"
oShellLink.Description = "Launch Unturned"
oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop + "\Unturned Dedicated Server"
oShellLink.Save
</Script></Job>
```

*If you wish to add your own batch-file code to this version it must be inserted just above the `@GoTo :EOF` line.*

Answer (score 0):

You should add another line where to put the arguments to be passed to your .exe target :

```
@echo off
Title Batch exe to shortcut
Set "VBS_Shortcut=%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
Set "ShortcutName=Unturned - Server"
Set "TargetPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe"
Set "Arguments=-batchmode -nographics +secureserver/ahhh"
Call :Create_Shortcut "%ShortcutName%" "%TargetPath%" "%Arguments%"
Exit
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Create_Shortcut
> "%VBS_Shortcut%" (
    echo    Call Create_Shortcut("%~1","%~2","%~3"^)
    echo    Sub Create_Shortcut(ShortcutName,TargetPath,Arguments^)
    echo        Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut
    echo        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo        DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
    echo        Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& ShortcutName ^& ".lnk"^)
    echo        objShortCut.TargetPath = chr(34^) ^& TargetPath ^& chr(34^)
    echo        objShortCut.Arguments = Arguments
    echo        objShortCut.Save
    echo    End Sub
)
cscript //nologo "%VBS_Shortcut%" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"
If Exist "%VBS_Shortcut%" Del "%VBS_Shortcut%" 
Exit /B
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```